# Magento 2: How to show list of users who didn't place any order with date fliter

Tags: magento2

Want to get a list of users who didn't place an order,What is the best way to get this list from magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of customers id from order table like:

> SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM `sales_order`

After it you can filter out customer collection using nin:

```
<?php

protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    ...
}

/**
 * Get customer collection
 */
public function getCustomerCollection()
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}


$customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('nin' => array(1,4,98)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Below is the best query to achieve this.

select email from customer_entity c, sales_order s where c.entity_id <> s.customer_id;

You can convert it in magento format

```
    $customer = $this->customerCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  $customer->getSelect()->join('sales_order as so', 'so.customer_id <> e.entity_id',[]);
```

Comment: ok, will try..thanks

Comment: your welcome @RahulSingh, It will work 100% , If it works for you could youplease give a vote for me